# Dajngo template not rendering content

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

When I render blogpost.html page I can't see any content in my page.

**My urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='Blog_home'),
    path('<slug:slug>', views.blogpost, name='blogpost'),
]
```

**my views.py**

When I print blogpost function's query I got null value

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from blog.models import Post

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    post = Post.objects.all()
    context = {'post':post}
    return render(request, 'blog/bloghome.html', context)

def blogpost(request, post_id):
    post = Post.objects.filter(slug=slug)
    print(post)
    context = {'post':post}
    return render(request, 'blog/blogpost.html', context)
```

**Template Name:- blogpost.html**

```
{% extends 'basic.html' %}

{% block title %}Blog{% endblock title %}

{% block body %}

<div class="contaier">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 py-4">
            <h2 class=" blog-post-title">{{post.title}}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock body %}
```

If I write like this my blogpost.html template it works.

```
{% extends 'basic.html' %}

{% block title %}Blog{% endblock title %}

{% block body %}

<div class="contaier">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 py-4">
            <h2 class=" blog-post-title">Django</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock body %}
```

[image: Check Out Problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a queryset as a context. Your `post` object contains a queryset of `Post` objects, so you can't retrieve `post.title`, you need either to pass only one `Post` object to your template, or loop through all of your objects and then display `post.title` for each of them.

You probably need the first option, so you need to change several things.

In your `urls.py`, you defined your `blogpost` view by `blogpost(request, post_id)` whereas in your `urls.py` you defined your url as

```
path('<slug:slug>', views.blogpost, name='blogpost')
```

If you want to get an id from your url, you should define it as

```
path('<int:post_id>', views.blogpost, name='blogpost')
```

And in your `blogpost` view, you do

```
post = Post.objects.filter(slug=slug)
```

but your slug isn't defined because your named it `post_id`.

Once again, if you want to retrieve only a post_id, you should use

```
post = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's not work

Comment: https://www.codewithharry.com/videos/python-django-tutorials-hindi-82/

Comment: Checkout this link

Comment: I've updated my answer as I noticed something else that wasn't correct

Comment: The difference with the link you gave me is the `slug` argument in the definition of your view, you renamed it `post_id` instead. And whether you use the `.first()` option on the queryset as in the tutorial, or you get an id from your url, but what you're doing right now is a mix of both and won't work since you retrieve several objects

Comment: Cannot resolve keyword 'id' into field. Choices are: author, content, date_and_time, post_id, slug, title 'New error'

Comment: Replace the `id` with `pk`

Comment: sorry bro but it's not work.

Comment: If you try to follow the tutorial you sent me, then just copy what's in it, that will work. Else please explain what your slug is in your url so that I can adapt my answer accordingly. Currently you're mixing several things so I can't know for sure what you want to achieve exactly

Comment: https://www.codewithharry.com/videos/python-django-tutorials-hindi-78/               'Start from here'

Comment: I can't help you with that, I don't know what you're refering to...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not retrieving a post with this:

```
post = Post.objects.filter(slug=slug)
```

It's a queryset, which returns zero, one, or possibly >1 objects (the latter if the slugfield isn't specified unique)

Try:

```
post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
```

or to better handle failure

```
post = get_object_or_404( Post, slug=slug)
```

Django template language fails quietly. If something in `{{ }}` fails, you get a null string substituted, not a runtime error.